# Serial Monitor appears unreadable characters

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

[image]

Hello

My serial monitor keep showing these unreadable characters. Anyone know what is going on? Many thanks!

[image: Schematic]
[image: Physical]
[image: Physical2]

---

Comment: maybe the data is binary, not ascii

Comment: Can you try a minimal example of `Serial.begin(9600); Serial.println("Hello world!");`?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Hi yes one line of hello world appeared

Comment: Then start adding connections, components and code until the error shows up. Does connecting RX to the Arduino change anything?

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt Yes connecting to RX looks normal but after connected ground to ground unreadable codes appear

Comment: Since the Serial connection to PC works correctly: Maybe you have changed the communication mode of the headset to 57600 baud like described on [this site](https://arduinoz.blogspot.de/2014/02/mindflex-headset-arduino-interfacing.html) (though this is a wild guess)

Answer (score 3):

It can have many reasons, but the most likely are:

- You set the baudrate wrong
- You set the stop/start bits wrong
- You send wrong data
- The cable is bad

It helps if you show your sketch(es), for sender/receiver and possibly your circuit.

Comment: Hi Michel thanks for your suggestions, these are my sketches and circuit: https://imgur.com/a/Ksg4w

Comment: It seems the baudrate is correct, start/stop bits is hard to see. Probably the date you send is wrong, you should check what happens in the Brains functions you call and what is returned (which is what you send).